# What to do when your question is already answered... but the answer is very old?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066625/how-would-i-skip-optional-arguments-in-a-function-call) is exactly the question I wish to ask, but it's five years old and I'm wondering if there's a different answer when using the current version of PHP.

What should I do?

Edit: And what would a new user be expected to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you could offer a bounty using one of the reasons specified in the [help center](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/). This one could be a good fit:

> **Current answers are outdated**
>
> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

Comment: I've created a bounty, but the description is not really a great fit, as I don't *know* that the answers require revision -- that's what I'm asking. I also have to wonder: What would a new user do?

Comment: Yes, I thought the same, there may or may not be a better solution in a newer language version. As per the new user part, the user could post a new question referencing the original question (so people know that he/she did some research), stating that the given solution is 5-6 years old, that he/she had tried it (show some effort), and that he/she'd be looking for a more recent/accurate/efficient solution for version x.x of the language (that didn't exist back then)... and still it could be considered a duplicate and voted to be closed

Answer (score 3):

Add a bounty to the question to seek out updated answers.

Comment: I have added a bounty, but what would a new user do?

Comment: @Chuck Post one decent post, and then post a bounty.

Comment: This is not a good answer. The aim of the site is to be repository for useful questions and answers. This only gets in the way of that.